# The mapping and metadata information for EntityContainer 'DBContext' no longer matches the information used to create the pre-generated views

Tags: entity-framework-5

This one was build before in MVC4.0 and EF4.0 Code First. Now it has been migrated in MVC5.0 AND EF5.0 Code First. During data migration it is getting the exception.